# Configure Bootstrapvalidator with CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

i have tutorial from this [page](http://bootstrapvalidator.votintsev.ru/examples/ckeditor/) about how to configure Bootstrapvalidator with CKEditor. i copied these codes and tested into my computer but when i run it i got an error the error message is like this

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Then i suggested maybe jquery link should be at the first to be referenced so i modify the code to be like this

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.3/basic/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.3/basic/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

but i have more error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

please help me how can i solve this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the jQuery library. The first JS seems to be one addon, not the JQuery library.

Add this line before the others.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ok and then i have new error                                                         
                                                                                                   
                                                   Uncaught TypeError: 
                                                   $(...).bootstrapValidator is not a 
                                                   function at HTMLDocument.

Comment: You should need the bootstrapValidator library for jQuery: https://plugins.jquery.com/bootstrapValidator/